# Why my javascript time string needs page to refresh to change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, meteor

I use following code to set time to user's messages in real-time on single-page using Meteor framework

```
var now = new Date();
var h = now.getHours();
var m = now.getMinutes();
var s = now.getSeconds();

var time = h + ":" + m + ':' + s;

Messages.insert({
                    name: name,
                    message: message.value,
                    time : time
                });
```

But time is incomplete with zeros and doesn't change unless page is refreshed :

- Matt at 14:4:51 : fdsfd
- Matt at 14:4:51 : fdsfds

Where is the problem with this ? You can see by yourself at http://hlavackachat.meteor.com/

Comment: You need to get the "Now" time when you display the messages. Currently you only get the time once and every time you display new messages the time is stored as the previous time hence it is not refreshed. You can declare a fuction and call it fuction when displaying messages.

Comment: @BongaMbombi thank you, I moved "now" to message function and it works just great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var TimeAddZero = function(_time)
{
    if(_time < 10)
    {
        _time = '0'+_time;
    }

    return _time;
};

var GetHHMMSS = function(_seconds)
{
    var hours = Math.floor(_seconds / 3600);
    var seconds = _seconds % 3600;
    var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    seconds = seconds % 60;
    hours = TimeAddZero(hours);
    minutes = TimeAddZero(minutes);
    seconds = TimeAddZero(seconds);
    return hours+':'+minutes+':'+seconds;
};

Messages.insert({
                    name: name,
                    message: message.value,
                    time : GetHHMMSS(Math.round(+new Date()/1000))
                });
```